# Protocol handler with multiple arguments

Tags: html, c++, url, browser, protocol-handler

I created an application to act as a protocol handler, the registry are set up according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Then in the webpage I have something like:

```
<a href="testapp:arg1">Test App</a>
```

If I click the link, the app is launched and "testapp:arg1" is passed in as an argument.

Now I want to pass multiple arguments to the handler. I'm guessing in the "command" registry key, I would have `"path_to_exe" "%1" "%2"`. However I can't figure out how to write the html link to supply multiple arguments.

Is it possible to pass multiple arguments? If so, how do I do it and are there differences between different browsers?

Answer (score 1):

In [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx), it says that

> When a user clicks a link containing your custom URI scheme, Windows Internet Explorer launches the pluggable protocol handler registered for that URI scheme. If the specified open command specified in the registry contains a %1 parameter, Internet Explorer passes the URI to the registered pluggable protocol handler application.

which means, spaces will be handled as the character in the whole URI.